# How to handle testing in marketing cloud? can you have a marketing cloud testing instance and push into a production instance as in SFDC via API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi, data-designer

We would like to have 2 instances of Marketing Cloud, one connected to Salesforce Sandbox and the other connected to Production.
Is it possible to replicate the structure and the assets using APIs?
We would like to have a solution that allows us to test the following

- Data designer and created data extensions
- Emails (we could do this by html copy paste)
- Journeys (thought about using Deployment manager export? Although my understanding is that this will export the structure but not the content. Eg the decision split will not be configured?)
  in the SFMC sandbox and then once tested pushed into another SFMC instance connected to SF production without having to edit it again.

Can the above be achieved with the APIs? what are the limitations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you license a brand new SFMC you should read up on multi-org setup for the marketing cloud connector. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_account_configuration.htm&type=5

The Deployment Manager is not that sophisticated yet. Therefore your understanding (for now) is correct.

You can do a lot of stuff with APIs. My question would be, if your goal is to sync between those instances or just set it up once. If a continuous "deployment" is the goal, APIs are the only way to do it for now. But you need to invest a lot of effort into it. But keep in mind that eventhough most features are available through API, not all of them are.
If you just want to have it cloned once and then do the rest manually, I would suggest at least asking Salesforce services, if they are able to do it. Because this can cost a lot of time and you can miss some configs etc.

Comment: Hi, the idea is that the new instance will be the testing enviroment before we deploy into the production as you do in SFDC. This will be an ongoing process. Eg new journey, once tested we get it created in the SFMC instance via api. I thought multiorg is not recommended for cross cloud projects where we sync a dev SF instance with one BU and a prod SF instance with another BU. 
The goal is to migrate and replicate 
- Journeys
- Content (ok to do with html paste)
- Changes to a preference page (again ok with HTML paste) 
- New data designer objects 
- Data extensions